# predicting age using machine learning model

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to machine learning and I am trying to learn and grow. I have stumbled upon this problem. I have this dataframe that contains these columns:

```
ispublicaccount country_AE  country_SA  age
```

now the ispublicaccount contains some missing data and the age (which i want to find the missing age) also contains missing data.

how can I create a machine learning model to predict the missing age values ?

I have the original dataframe: df_simplified

```
ispublicaccount|country_AE|country_SA|age|
1               1          0         |41
2               1          0          NaN
1               0          1          NaN
NaN             1          0          23
0               0          1          31
1               0          1          NaN
1               0          1          19
2               1          0          24
.....
```

of course there are a lot more data but this is in a nuthsell

now I know how to create a model and predict if I have full dataset with no missing values then I would create a model and fit the data and predict. but how can I deal with these missing data in here and predict the missing age values? thank you for your helpp

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi Mohammad, welcome to SO. This question is a little broad. Do you mind condensing what information you'd like? From your question it seems like you want to remove the rows with NA values from this Pandas dataframe. Is that right?

Comment: hello @JashShah , sorry this is my first time asking a question! I think yes the first step is to remove the NA values! but should I remove the NA values from the age column? which is the column that I want to predict the values of

Comment: im not sure I understand what you are looking for here? can you please be more specific on what specific coding answer you are stuck with? Is it how to find NaN values? If this is just "how to do machine learning" I would suggest starting wiht ML courses or googling how to best practices for pythong ML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

deal with missing values is a big issue in ML, you could delete the row with missing values if you have enough data but if you dong you could replace them with the last valid observation or with the mean value or median
I think if you can't delete rows with missing values, consider using mean instead of NANs.
to drop rows you could use this:

```
data['age']
```

and to replace with mean value, use this:

```
data['age'].fillna(value=data['age'].mean(), inplace=True)
```